# How to add Default value in spinner in android?

Tags: spinner

How to add the default value in spinner like selectone? I want to add one value in spinner that is visible on spinne,r but when I click on spinner all the values of adapter get displayed in front of me but not selectone which is the default value.

```java
    try {

            json = new JSONObject(Status);

            // nameArray = json.names();

            valArray = json.getJSONArray("Machines");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        for (int i = 0; i < valArray.length(); i++) {

            try {

                String machineName = valArray.getJSONObject(i)

                        .getString("MachineName").toString();

                // Integer machineID = Integer.parseInt(valArray.getJSONObject(

                // 0).getString("MachineID"));

                // Entities.machineID = machineID;

                adapter.add(machineName);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }



        sp_Machine.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: can you be a bit more clear? Please elaborate your question

Comment: Basically i want default item selected in spinner as SelectOne for example :- like spinner for countries and default item in that spinner is Select Country is selected, when activity loads and after clicking on spinner for selecting any item that Select Country is not there in the spinner list .

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the values of the spinner dynamically, then this is the way to add select at first of the spinner value:

```
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/classname_spinner.php");
    try{
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);

        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("output");
        arr = new String[jArray.length()+1];
        arr[0] = "-select-";
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String sclass = json_data.getString("spinner");
            arr[i+1] = sclass;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag","Error parsing classname data"+e.toString());
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag","Request failed"+e.toString());
}
```

now add the value you got to the spinner as shown below:

```
classSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editClass);
    ArrayAdapter<String> classNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr);
    classNameAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    classSpinner.setAdapter(classNameAdapter);
```

Now when want the spinner to get back to its default value on on click event, then just write in your on click event as:

```
reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                classSpinner.setSelection(0);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: my data is coming from webservice its dynamically

Comment: k then, i guess I've to update my answer, but update ur question by adding the code so that I could be more specific...

Comment: I edited  my question above i want that select in spinner disable

Comment: @SachinGurnani now check the answer. Hope this helps you... and sorry for updating my answer a bit late...

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution i came up with a while back. just use this adapter instead of a regular one:

```java
    package perelman.yuval.carsapp;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class SpinnerDualAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
    private boolean isPromptAdapter;
    private SpinnerDualAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public SpinnerDualAdapter(Context context,
            int textViewResourceIdForDropdownView,
            int textViewResourceIdForDefaultView, List<T> objects,
            String defaultValue) {
        this(context, textViewResourceIdForDropdownView, objects);
        ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myArrayList.add(defaultValue);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                textViewResourceIdForDefaultView, myArrayList);
        isPromptAdapter=true;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(isPromptAdapter){
                isPromptAdapter=false;
                return myAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
            TextView tv=new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setText(this.getItem(position).toString());
        return tv;
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        isPromptAdapter=false;
        return(super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent));
    }
    }
```